# Using a $var in a mysqli WHERE LIKE statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a list of items in a region.

I'd like the Region Name as a Heading
Then all the items in that region in a table below
i.e.

HEADING - Region1

Table - Region1 Items

HEADING - Region2

Table - Region2 Items

HEADING - Region3

Table - Region3 Items

HEADING - Region4

Table - Region4 Items

I can output:

HEADING

HEADING

HEADING

I can output the region details in a table if I use LIKE 'Actual Region Name'

I would like to output using LIKE $region so I don't need to write a new statement for each 'Actual Region Name'.

The 2 SELECT Queries:

```
$region = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT region FROM country") or die($conn->error);
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM country WHERE region LIKE '$region'") or die($conn->error);
```

OUTPUT 1

This outputs each region as

Region Name

```
$i = 0;
while($row = $region->fetch_assoc())
{
 if ($i == 0) {
 foreach ($row as $value) {
 echo "<p>" . $value . "</p>";
                      }

             }
}
```

OUTPUT 2

This outputs all the region data and puts it in a table.

```
echo "This is table Build";
echo "<table border='1'>";

$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    if ($i == 0) {
      $i++;
      echo "<tr>";
      foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $value) {
      echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

OUTPUT 1 and OUTPUT 2 both work separately.
I can't get them to work together

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: This should not be using two queries to begin with. Write one query, that gets you all the data, properly sorted - and then implement a simple [control break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break).

Comment: @04FS Don't suppose you'd like to elaborate on the single query that might help me?
I've been googling and trying different options for hours - that's why I'm here.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all `region` names from query and then passed it to your `next query` and print all the `record` related to that query i.e :

```
<?php

$region = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT region FROM country") or die($conn->error);

if($region->num_rows > 0) 
    {                               {
       while($row = $region->fetch_assoc())
         {
         //printing region name
         echo "<p>" . $row['region'] . "</p>";
         //only those row will be retrieve which belong to current region name 
         $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM country WHERE region LIKE '$row['region']'") or die($conn->error);
//printing table 
      echo "This is table Build";
      echo "<table border='1'>"; 
              $i = 0;
    while($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if ($i == 0) {
          $i++;
          echo "<tr>";
          foreach ($row1 as $key => $value) {
            echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
          }
          echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row1 as $value) {
          echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
             }

}
  mysqli_close($conn);

        ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Swati
That gives me an error : Undefined index: region
on this line
if($row['region '] !=$region){

Comment: there is little space here `$row['region ']` remove that space i.e : `$row['region']` and check onces

Comment: Still showing as undefined

Comment: Does `$row['region']` exist ? I mean column `region` ? Also is this error on `$row['region']` or `$region` ?

Comment: Yes region exists as a column.
Using the $region = SELECT DISTINCT...
I can list out all the region names using the code in OUTPUT 1

Comment: I have edited the original post, as I'm not sure it was completely clear what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood your question , now check updated code, this should work.

Comment: Thank you!
That's exactly what I was trying to do. I had to make 1 change in the $result line `LIKE '".$row['region']."'`

Comment: Great it worked , try to accept this answer if it helped you :)